# Fire a directive at ng-click event in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, directive

Let say that I have

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-click="MyControllerFunction()" ng-tracking pageevent="button_clicked">click me</div>
```

I cannot change this structure at all and I need, from my directive ngTracking, catch this pageevent when this button is clicked.

Remember, I don't want to touch the controller or even the DOM in this case.

is this possible be done only with the directive? If not, is there any other solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, thank you.

`elm.bind('click', function () {
       console.log(attrs.pageevent);
});`